# Angular calling a parent method from an extended controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I been spinning on this for days with no luck. I have `BaseController` with an `init` method among other things. I then wish to extend this controller and call the parents 'init' method from within the childs 'init' method.

The general answer for this is to call `$scope.$parent.init($settings_object)`. However this is returning `Error: $scope.$parent.init is not a function`.

Generally the extended controller works fine being able to access the perents function and settings without issues. Just this example calling the same parent method from the child fails.

BaseController

```js
(function( ){
 var mainApp = angular.module("MyAppModule");      
 mainApp.controller('BaseController',function($scope, $rootScope,GLOBAL_CONFIG, ajaxRESTful,sharedValues, messageDisplay) { //base contorller
       var bvm = this; //base vm

       this.init = function($settings_object){
        var keys = Object.keys($settings_object);
        for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
         bvm[keys[i]] = $settings_object[keys[i]];
         
        }
       }
       
          //code remved to keep simple
      
 });
})();
```

Extended controller

```js
(function( ){
var app = angular.module('MyAppModule');
 app.controller('RoleEdit', function($scope, $rootScope,$controller) {
  angular.merge(this, $controller('BaseController', {$scope: $scope}));
  var vm = this;
  vm.newRoleFormData = [];
  vm.role_id = null; 
  vm.mode = 'create';
  vm.role = null;
      
  vm.init = function ($object) {
   console.log(vm);
   console.log($scope.$parent);
   $scope.$parent.init($object);
             if(vm.role_id != null){
               vm.loadInRole( );
             }
     };
  

  
 }) //end contoller

})();//end of app
```

Why doesn't this work?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: init is not in the scope. change it to scope. it will work. $scope.init = ..

Comment: consider maybe a service for talking between controllers. best practice. you can also talk by $rootScope which is not the best way.

Comment: Forget that $parent even exists in angular. It's very very rare you need to use it as there is usually a better way. Use services to connect controllers together

Comment: Then was is the best way to init these controllers? The method is called via `ng-init="create.init({msg_panel_id:'cre_role',role:'display',role_id:'47'})" ng-controller="RoleEdit as details"` This init need to be fun in both the child and parent.

Answer (score 4):

The controller object (`this`) and the `$scope` object aren't directly related. There is no automatic wiring between them. `$scope.$parent` doesn't return a controller, it returns the parent scope. And since you registered your parent method in `this.init` instead of the usual `$scope.init`, you can't expect to find it using scopes.

You may circumvent this in a great number of ways, but as others have suggested, if you have functionality that is shared by many controllers, try to put it in a service instead. Maybe your `BaseContoller` itself should be a service.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
var parentInit = this.init.bind(this);
this.init = function ($object) {
  parentInit($object);
  if(vm.role_id != null){
    vm.loadInRole( );
  }
}
```